# Tensor character of a Jacobian transformation (Tensor Calculus by J.L.Synge Ex1 #9)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems

I am trying to solve this question in Synge’s Tensor Calculus, Exercise 1 question #9.

[image: Image of the question]

I don't know how to approach this question. $\frac{\partial{x^r}}{\partial{y^s}}$ are the components of the Jacobian transformation from coordinate system $x$ to $y$. How can I examine the tensor character of a Jacobian? Also, how will the unchanged coordinates come into play?

Comment: Maybe rephrasing the question will help: "The Jacobian is a tensor, with indices $r$ and $s$. For each index, determine whether it is covariant or contravariant." In Einstein notation, this could be rephrased as: "For each index, determine whether it is an upper or a lower index."

Comment: @probably_someone I can see that the chain rule expansion can prove that the indices will transform a certain way. However, for the variables that are unchanged, will that not be a conclusive test, since any derivative of a constant quantity is zero?